# Is the Sunan Abi Dawud Hadith on executing the people of Lut reliable?

Tags: hadith, homosexuality

> Narrated Abdullah ibn Abbas:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: If you find anyone doing as Lot's people did, kill the one who does it, and the one to whom it is done.

Abu Dawud said: A similar tradition has also been transmitted by Sulaiman b. Bilal from 'Amr b. Abi 'Umar. And 'Abbad b. Mansur transmitted it from 'Ikrimah on the authority of Ibn 'Abbas who transmitted it from the Prophet (ﷺ). It has also been transmitted by Ibn Juraij from Ibrahim from Dawud b. Al-Husain from 'Ikrimah on the authority of Ibn 'Abbas who transmitted it from the Prophet (ﷺ).

Grade   : Hasan Sahih (Al-Albani)

However I came across an article stating that due to it chain of narrators it is not reliable this is what it states:

Sunan Abi Dawud, Hadith No. 4465); (Sunan al-Tirmidhi, Hadith No. 1456).

This tradition is narrated on the authority of only two of the companions of the Prophet, namely Ibn Abbas and Abu Hurayra. Thus, it is classified as khabar al-wahid, which means a hadith related by a single authority or through a solitary chain of transmission. There are other versions of this tradition attributed to Jabir b. Abdullah (d. 697 CE) and Ali b. Abi Talib. Both were classified as “very weak” and unreliable. Other versions of this tradition do not mention the death penalty or any punishment. None of the traditions attributed to the Prophet Muhammad on this subject was accepted as authentic or “strong”, even by a small group of hadith scholars.

The eminent hadith scholar and jurist Jamal al-Din al-Zayla‘i (d. 1361) provided a detailed analysis of all the chains of transmission of this hadith and cited numerous renowned authorities in the field of hadith such as Yahya Ibn Ma‘in (d. 848), Al-Bukhari (d. 870), Al-Tirmidhi (d. 892), Al-Nasa’i (d. 915), Al-Dhahabi (d. 1348) and others who classified it and all its various chains of transmission as “unreliable”, “very weak”, “inauthentic” and “unfounded”. (See, Al-Zayla‘i, Jamal al-Din, Nasb al-raya: Takhrij ahadith al-Hidaya, Jeddah: Dar al-Qibla, nd. Vol.3, pp. 339-340)

The only scholar known to have classified it as authentic is al-Hakim Nisapuri (d. 1014CE) who recorded it in his collection entitled al-Mustadrak. However, al-Hakim Nisapuri acquired a reputation among hadith scholars as a careless critic of hadith whose verdicts can only be deemed credible when endorsed by the eminent scholar al-Dhahabi. As mentioned above, al-Dhahabi rejected this tradition and classified it as unreliable.

I would like to know if this is true

Comment: I would like to know your source of information. As there's not that much to say against the narrator chain, so al-Hakim from Nisapur seems falsely "accused" in that source. It is mostly qualified as hassan (good), by many scholars. But there's a difference of opinion among scholars about the ruling. Especially abu Hanifa doesn't seem to agree to the content of this hadith and the book you refer to is of Hanafi jurisprudence.

Comment: Here is the source:http://www.altmuslimah.com/2016/06/death-penalty-homosexual-acts-violation-sharia/

Comment: So ultimately this hadith is Hassan ?